# Using formula with vba and copy another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with a text in every cell to extract, in some way, in another column.

I make this vba script but doesn't work for apply the formula in another column for every cell, it make as a loop and i don't see nothing.

```
Sub CommandButtonClick()
 Dim Addr As String
 Addr = Range("E2:E") & Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row).Address
 Range(Addr) = Evaluate("SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-
 FIND("=>",E2)),CHAR(62),"")")
END Sub
```

And this to copy the result in another workbook:

```
Sub copyresult()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(" ticketsosurgenti ")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(" ticketsos ")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C").Copy
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D").Copy
'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A").PasteSpecial
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B").PasteSpecial
'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: you cannot copy twice and then paste twice. You need to copy first paste first, copy second paste second. Otherwise the second copy overwrites the first copy action.

Comment: Also you are copying a Range `C2:C` without and end row number, which will give you an error `Run-time error 1004`, you need to find the last row and copy using the full range such as `Range("C2:C10").Copy`

Comment: Another thing is that when you .Open the workbooks I'm pretty sure you should include the full file name, such as `Workbooks.Open("tickesosurgenti.xlsx")`

Comment: Probably not only the full file name but even the full path `Workbooks.Open("C:\my\path\tickesosurgenti.xlsx")` if they are not in the same place as `ThisWorkbook.Path`

Comment: Ok, thanks i think i could use C2:C because i  have a lot of row about 20000. And for the evaluate function. Doens't work when i click on the button it make a loop and nothing appear.

Comment: @ElisSc I don't understand what you are trying to do with the evaluate function, if you could clarify your desired outcome, then we could provide a better answer...

Comment: @ElisSc "*Doesn't work*" is no useful error description. Describe what you expected and what it did instead, or if it showed any error messages. Also it is unclear what you mean when you say "*it make a loop and nothing appear*" there is no loop in your code at all. Describe everything at detailed as possible in your original question. Try to qualify a worksheet for every `Range` and `Cells` like `Worksheets("MySheet").Range` otherwise VBA tries to guess which sheet you mean.

Comment: Also this `Addr = Range("E2:E") & Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row).Address` is no valid syntax, this won't even compile (becomes red font color)! Try `Addr = Range("E2:E") & Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row` instead. If you then still have questions update your original question with your actual code first.

Answer (score 0):

For the copying and pasting between workbooks, the following should help:

```
Sub copyresult()
     Dim x As Workbook
     Dim y As Workbook
     Dim LastRow As Long
     '## Open both workbooks first:
     Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:/ticketsosurgenti.xlsx")
     Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:/ticketsos.xlsx")
     'above amend the path and filename of both your workbooks
     Dim wsX As Worksheet: Set wsX = x.Sheets("Sheet1")
     Dim wsY As Worksheet: Set wsY = y.Sheets("Sheet1")

     LastRow = wsX.Cells(wsX.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     'get the last row with data on Column A on Sheet x

     wsX.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Copy
     wsY.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

     wsX.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy
     wsY.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

     x.Close
 End Sub
```